# Does calling an empty method in java use resources?

Tags: java, performance

The reason I am asking is because in my program I have a parent class which holds methods which may or may not be used by the child class. I am just curious to know if the compiler optimizes this for each child instance, or does it require the small bit of resource to check to see if something is there?

Comment: I can't speak to whether the java compiler optimizes out the empty method call, but for performance problems in java , such areas are usually not the place to look. This answer may be useless just from the point of answering your question but I have run a lot of performance exercises and there are more important issues to consider than this in all practicality.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM uses certain heuristics to decide what methods to inline. The method needs to be a hotspot (i.e. being invoked enough times to make the inlining worthwhile), it shouldn't be very big and it shouldn't be overridden by child classes (which would modify its behaviour and invalidate the optimization). There are probably other heuristics too.

In your case, if these empty methods are never overridden, and they are invoked enough times, they will probably be inlined.

Instead of guessing, you can also enable java command line flags to see what the JIT is doing (i.e. if it inlines or not the methods). See this blog post: https://techblug.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/java-jit-compiler-inlining/